# Mapping a custom NHibernate class (like a view)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have several classes/mappings ... Its all working fine...
Sometimes a create a view for better performance ...

I´d like to know if it´s posible to create a special mapping without creating the DB view...

Example, I have :

```
class Test
{
  Test2 test2;
  string a;
} 

class Test2
{
  Test3 test3;
  string x;
} 

class Test3
{
  Test4 test4;
  string y;
}
```

I´d like to create a class/mapping (without creating a db view) like that:

```
class CustomTest
{
   string test_a;
   string Test2_x;
   string Test2_y;
}
```

Is it posible?

Comment: Is `CustomTest` a readonly class? or do you want to send updates to three tables?

Comment: No, Update to three tables...

Comment: I dont think this is possible with mapping alone, you will need to handroll your own `Update` rather than relying on the session being dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a class/mapping for one association but not nested. You could go with custom sql in the mapping but i think the following is easier.

```
Test2 test2alias= null;
Test3 test3alias = null;
CustomTest view = null;

var results = session.QueryOver<Test>()
    .JoinAlias(t => t.Test2, () => test2alias)
    .JoinAlias(() => test2alias.Test3, () => test3alias)
    .SelectList(x => 
    {
        x.Select(t => t.a).WithAlias(() => view.a)
        x.Select(() => test2alias.x).WithAlias(() => view.x)
        x.Select(() => test3alias.y).WithAlias(() => view.y)
    })
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<CustomTest>())
    .List<CustomTest>()
```

note: this is for readonly access

Second Try: as its not possible to do this with standard mapping

```
class CustomTest
{
    public virtual string A { get; set; }

    private Test2 _test2;
    private Test2 Test2 { get { return _test2 ?? (_test2 = new Test2()); } set { _test2 = value; } }

    public virtual string X
    {
        get { return Test2.X; }
        set { Test2.X = value; }
    }

    private Test3 Test3
    {
        get { return Test2.Test3 ?? (Test2.Test3 = new Test3()); }
        set { Test2.Test3 = value; }
    }

    public virtual string Y
    {
        get { return Test3.Y; }
        set { Test3.Y = value; }
    }
}

class CustomTestMap : ClassMap<CustomTest>
{
    public CustomTestMap()
    {
        Table("Test1Table");

        // Id() same as Test1

        Map(ct => ct.A);
        References(Reveal.Member<CustomTest>("Test2")).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

// alternativly which is brittle and timeconsuming and doesnt allow selects (or most of them)

```
class CustomTestMap : ClassMap<CustomTest>
{
    public CustomTestMap()
    {
        Table("Test1Table");

        Id(...)

        SqlInsert("INSERT INTO Test1Table (...) VALUES (?, ...); INSERT INTO Test2Table (...) VALUES (?, ...); INSERT INTO Test2Table (...) VALUES (?, ...)");
        SqlUpdate("UPDATE Test1Table SET ...; UPDATE ...");
        SqlDelete("UPDATE Test1Table SET ...; UPDATE ...");
        SqlDeleteAll(...);

        Map(ct => ct.A);
        Map(ct => ct.X);
        Map(ct => ct.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not correct as the user wants to have a class that is auto updating.